# Android scrollview is not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

I have this layout with a scrollview inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background="#eeeeee">

     <!-- HEADER -->

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:orientation="vertical" >        
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="1dp"
             android:background="#868686"
             android:orientation="vertical" >        
         </LinearLayout>

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/parent_linear"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:background="@drawable/gradient_header" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:text="@string/proposed_plan_prompt"
                 android:textColor="#797A77"
                 android:textSize="15sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

         </RelativeLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="2dp"
             android:background="#C7C7C7"
             android:orientation="vertical" >        
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="3dp"
             android:background="@drawable/gradient_header_separator" 
             android:orientation="vertical" >        
         </LinearLayout>

     </LinearLayout>

     <!-- BODY -->

     <!-- Proposed plan (summary) -->
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:background="@drawable/border"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/providerNameView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />         

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/planView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="1234"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="#737373"/>

         </LinearLayout>

         <View
            android:id="@+id/separator" 
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_vertical" />

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_gravity="right"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                 android:gravity="top"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/priceView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:text="XY"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:text="+123"
                    android:textColor="#565756"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

             </LinearLayout>

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/totPriceView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="right"
                 android:text="(information)"
                 android:textColor="#737373"
                 android:textSize="12sp" />

         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Choose:"
             android:textSize="12sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <SeekBar
             android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:text="Best"
             android:textColor="#737373"
             android:textSize="12sp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/detailsTextView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:text="Details:"
         android:textSize="12sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
         android:background="@drawable/border"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <FrameLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <ScrollView
                 android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="right"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
                     android:background="@drawable/border"
                     android:orientation="vertical" >

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line1Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#ffffff"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line1Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line1Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line2Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#EAEAEA"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line2Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line2Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line3Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#ffffff"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line3Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line3Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line4Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#EAEAEA"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line4Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line4Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line5Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#ffffff"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line5Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line5Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/line6Layout"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="30sp"
                         android:background="#EAEAEA"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line6Title"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/line6Text"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                             android:background="@drawable/border_attribute"
                             android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
                             android:visibility="invisible" />
                     </RelativeLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="140dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                 android:src="@drawable/robin4" />
         </FrameLayout>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_proposed_extras"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
             android:background="@drawable/button_transparent"
             android:text="@string/extras_title"
             android:textColor="#298A17"
             android:textStyle="bold|italic"
             android:visibility="invisible" />
     </LinearLayout>

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_proposed_change"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/button"
         android:text="@string/proposition_change_title"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button_proposed_no_change"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normal"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/button_silver"
         android:text="@string/proposition_no_change_title"
         android:textColor="#298A17"
         android:textStyle="bold" /> 


 </LinearLayout>
```

- The part with the scrollview displays at maximum size and is not scrolling.
- The two buttons at the end are not displayed, they apparently don't fit in the screen.

I'd like to have the scroll working in order to have buttons appearing.

Why the scrolled layout is displayed at max size instead of being scrolled?

What would be the solution?

Comment: Can we have a screen shot of this layout ?

Answer (score 2):

For making the buttons to appear in the screen you should have the buttons within the scroll too. Mostly, the screens that you design should have scrollview as the parent if the screen contains many components. Main ScrollView -> LinearLayout / RelativeLayout -> Add Components as needed. By doing so you should have be able to see the buttons also. In doing this way even if your layout changes to landscape the components wont get hidden and will be shown in the scroll. Hope you get my point and it helps you in solving your issue.

As far as the code above is concerned you will not be able to see the buttons as buttons are not within scrollview and hence the view below is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't scroll because its height is wrap_content.

Comment: I tried every parameter for the height and it did change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As ChristopheCVB stated, your ScrollView needs to NOT be `wrap_content`. A ScrollView will only scroll if the content it contains is larger (read *taller* for a vertical ScrollView and *wider* for a horizontal ScrollView) that the ScrollView itself. If it is smaller, then it has no need to scroll.